# Show particular div and hide all another after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three div elements:

```
<div class="hide_banner" id="1"><img src="1.png"></div>
<div class="hide_banner" id="2"><img src="2.png"></div>
<div class="hide_banner" id="3"><img src="3.png"></div>
```

After the page is loaded the user should see the 1st div only. Here is the JS/jQ code (this works perfectly):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide_banner').not('#' + 1).hide(3000);
});
```

The user can pick another banner by click at links on this page:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#1" class="show_banner">Image 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" class="show_banner">Image 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3" class="show_banner">Image 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

After click for example on the 3rd link (href="#3") the div with id="1" should hide and the div with id="3" shold be shown. I have an idea how to maintain the problem combaining with PHP, but i want to solve it with JS/jQ only, so please help! ;) Here is my JS/jQ code which doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide_banner').not('#' + 1).hide(3000);
  $('a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    if(id == 1) {
        $(id).show(3000);
        $('#2').hide(3000);
        $('#3').hide(3000);

    }

    if(id == 2) {
        $(id).show(3000);
        $('#1').hide(3000);
        $('#3').hide(3000);

    }

    if(id == 3) {
        $(id).show(3000);
        $('#1').hide(3000);
        $('#2').hide(3000);

    }
  });

});
```

P.s.: I know that it is incorrect to start id's names with a number ;)

Comment: Note: Numeric ID values are a HTML 5 feature... best not to use them in practice (until HTML 4 is dead and buried) :)

Comment: It's a lot easier than you think -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wa51p6ue/**

Comment: @adeneo - its even easier than *you* think - check teh 2 similar answers!

Comment: @Jamiec: Were you really just smug to `136K` adeneo? Brave man :>

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I'm releasing the hounds as we speak ...

Comment: @adeneo: Great... This place needs more hounds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, no need for `if...else` logic here, nor any need to specify the first id - just use `:first`:

```js
$('.hide_banner').not(':first').hide(3000);
$('a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).show(3000);
    $('.hide_banner').not(id).hide(3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide_banner" id="1">1</div>
<div class="hide_banner" id="2">2</div>
<div class="hide_banner" id="3">3</div>


<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#1" class="show_banner">Image 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" class="show_banner">Image 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3" class="show_banner">Image 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to use jQuery `not`, so use it to exclude the selected target:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vk94mmv2/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hide_banner:not(:first)').hide(3000);
    $('a').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var $show = $(id);
        $show.show(3000);
        $('.hide_banner').not($show).hide(3000);
    });
});
```

Note: you can change the first selector to use the `:not(:first)` pseudo selectors to select all but the first banner.

Comment: it doesn't work... but thx for the tip with ':not(:first)' :)

Comment: @daru79: Sorry, which part doesn't work? The code is effectively the same as `Jamiec`s. You did notice my comment about the extra class I added as the use of hide_banner was not clear I hope? :)

Comment: sorry, my fault! :/ i havent noticed it!

Comment: @daru79: I have updated it back to your original HTML so less confusion :)